# Create a string SQL query with a loop, PHP

Tags: php, sql

Last night I was thinking in a code part that I don't have it automated...
That's why I don't has it has a object... One line of code is what I need to make it to a object a use it for a any project.

What I want is:

1. Create a dynamic variables with a loop. (This is done and is a good idea)
2. Create a dynamic SQL query with the variables that was created dynamic (This is what I want to do)

**Here we create a dynamic variables with a for loop:**

```
    /* This variables has the inputs of an HTML
    * inputs are the name of a input, in this example there are 2, email and pass
    * inputs_val store the value of email and pass
    $inputs;
    $inputs_val;

    // Starting with an array        
    $arrayName = array();
    // Then with a for loop we fill the array
    for ($i=0; $i < count($inputs_val); $i++) {
                // While $i are less than 2 (email, pass) $i++
        $var_nom = $inputs[$i];
        $var_val = $inputs_val[$i];
        $arrayName[$i] = $var_val;
                // if we want to store the input name we use:
                // $arrayName[$var_nom] = $var_val;
    }
```

**My question is here:**

How you create an string SQL query looping the array?

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($arrayName); $i++) { 
     $query = "SELECT usr_email, usr_pass FROM tbl_usr WHERE usr_email='$arrayName[$i]' AND usr_pass='$arrayName[$i]' LIMIT 1;";
}
```

The error is there: usr_email='$arrayName[$i]' and usr_pass='$arrayName[$i]'
Because when the loop start with 0 is OK for usr_email, but not for usr_pass and when the loop pass again is OK for usr_pass but not for usr_email...

I try with a $i2 = $i+1; but also doesn't work.

Suggest and ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$arrayName[$i] can't be at the same time an email and a password. That's why it didn't work.

If I well understand what you want, you can do something like that :

```
$inputs;
$inputs_val;
$arrayName = array();
for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($inputs_val) ; i++)
  $arrayName[$inputs[$i]][] = $inputs_val[$i];
```

And then (with $inputs containing "user_email" and "user_pass") :

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($arrayName['usr_email']); $i++) { 
     $query = "SELECT usr_email, usr_pass FROM tbl_usr WHERE usr_email='$arrayName['user_email'][$i]' AND usr_pass='$arrayName['user_pass'][$i]' LIMIT 1;";
}
```